# R: substract the Y column as a matrix

Tags: r, col

I have a table called test (imported with read.csv) that looks like this:

```
Y   X1   X2   ...   X100
0   125   a   ...   32
1   163   b   ...   25
0   758   b   ...   587
```

I have succeeded saving all the predictors in a different table with the following command:

```
x_test <- test[, !(colnames(test) %in% c("Y"))]
```

When I type

```
fix(x_test)
```

I get a beautiful table with all the predictors.
I cannot seem to do the same for Y.
Any help?

Comment: Your code can be shortened as: test[!names(test)=="Y"]  (after removing unnecessary comma, brackets and 'c')

Comment: maybe so but it works just fine so I have no reason not to use it

Comment: @lore I guess the `==` would be a bit faster compared to `%in%` especially when you have one term to compare.  Anyway, it is just a comment.  You are free to use whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is helpful. Insufficient rep to ask for information in a comment, so I'll jump in with something. I don't know what class your loaded object is (or the columns therein), but you might try ensuring it's a data frame, then using subset:

```
#create some random nonsense
set.seed(123)
junk1 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100,5,.5),ncol=1,nrow=100))
junk2 = data.frame(matrix(1:100,ncol=100,nrow=100))
colnames(junk1)="Y"
test=cbind(junk1,junk2)

#should at this point have a data.frame something like your data, first column Y, rest X1..X100
#if yours isn't already, after doing your "test=read.csv(file)" then "test=as.data.frame(test)"

x_test = subset(test,select=colnames(test)[colnames(test)!="Y"])
y_test = subset(test,select="Y")
```

using the subset may not be the best way, but has the advantage that even when extracting a single column (as in the case of your "Y") the result will be a data frame, rather than a vector.

EDIT: props to Sven who I just saw enquired about the class (didn't see before posting this)

Comment: I get the same result. The response variable is present and the predictors are empty. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hrm. Sorry then. Is the response variable the "Y" column then? Could you show what you're getting that is not the table you want? Sven's (more experienced) comment about the class of test may solve it, if the table you've read in can't be coerced to a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want

```
test["Y"]
```

instead of `test[ , "Y"]`.

Comment: @lore  The outcome of `test["Y"]` should be a data frame with one column. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @lore What is the result of `class(Y_test)`?

Comment: @lore What is the output of `class(test)`?